# Find maximum sum of K elements in a graph with unary and binary terms

Tags: algorithms, graphs, clique

I have an algorithmic problem that I managed to reduce to the following form:

Given a graph with $N$ elements, select exactly $K$ elements to maximize the following:

$$
\max \Sigma_{k \in K} V(S_k) + \Sigma_{k \in K} \Sigma_{j \in K} E(S_k, S_j)
$$

The unary values $V$ and binary values $E$ can be considered given. They can be made non-negative if necessary.

Does this problem have name? Is it optimizable or solvable? Or is there a related known problem?

Comment: $K$ is a set or a number?

Comment: Please define all notation.  What is $S_k$?  What is $V(S_k)$ and $E(S_k,S_j)$?  I don't understand what you mean by "the unary values $V$".  Are you looking to pick a set of $K$ vertices, and the graph has weights on the vertices and edges?  I encourage you to [edit] your post to clarify.

Comment: Note that finding a clique (of size $k$) can be reduced to this problem if you set $V(x)$ to a constant and $E(u, v)$ is 1 only for edges in the graph.